# How to install object-detection library without downgrading Python version?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, python-3.5

I am trying to install object-detection library using cmd but having an issue

I tried

pip install object-detection

I am getting this error

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.0.3 Requires-Python >=3.5, !=3.7.*
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement object-detection (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for object-detection

Is there anyway i can install it without requiring to either uninstall the current python ersion I have or without needing to install an older versin?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't uninstall your current Python version. But you could try and install a *newer* Python version instead. For me, Pyenv works well for that purpose. Or perhaps Conda (in the form of Miniconda) can be of use for you. If you do install another Python version, preferably make it a user-only installation; any use of `sudo` (or admin, in case of Windows) should not be necessary.

Comment: Note that the requirements don't exclude e.g. Python 3.11. However, given that the latest and only release was in Jan 2019, that may not work. 3.8 or 3.9 may work. Then again, given the version number of 0.0.3 and the single release, it looks like this package was made as a brief project, put on PyPI, then abandoned. It wouldn't use it.

Comment: The package looks to be a mistake or attempted trial  of some sort; the "homepage" link leads to a fork of Tensorflow, and the `object-detection` package seems to be simply part of Tensorflow. It is likely you're better off installing Tensorflow and go with that. Do note the following [in the object-detection part in the Tensorflow repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection): "Note to our users: the Tensorflow Object Detection API is no longer being maintained to be compatible with new versions of external dependencies (from pip, apt-get etc.)"